# Can you upload files to github pages via browser?

Tags: javascript, html, file, github, upload

I'm trying to design a music website that involves users uploading mp3 files and sharing them. Is it possible to do this with Github Pages or would I need a different hosting service? Like if I created a submit button with javascript, could the files be stored in the github repo?

Thanks.

Comment: Github pages can only host Static web pages , but you can use external Ajax Calls to upload those files on Different Service. anyway i don't recommand that as of Github isn't meant for this use .

Answer (score 2):

GitHub Pages is designed to handle only static sites. While it is possible to use JavaScript, in order to make your concept work securely, you'd need some sort of server-side code to upload the files, which isn't possible on GitHub Pages.

In addition, GitHub and Git aren't a good fit for storing things like user uploads which don't generally need versioning. Some sort of file or object storage would be a better fit and perform much better.

Comment: Hello bk2204! I'm interested in this subject and I wanted to know if you recommend any service, or any approach for accomplishing what you said (in my case, I must use GitHub pages) or I must find another free hosting platform. I'm also a beginner in web development, so I'm sorry for any silly/naive question.